# Tomcat 5.5 doesn't recognize DataSource at startup (Null component Catalina:type=DataSource)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, datasource, jndi

I have set up a Postgres 9.0.1 SQL server and a Tomcat 5.5.28 both at my local PC. Both are running fine. But I have not been able to configure Tomcat to make the DataSource available via JNDI. I think I have followed the JNDI HOW-TO from the Tomcat pages to the letter (as well as having tried some other how-to's from other pages, too). But everytime Tomcat starts he displays the error message:

```
SEVERE: Null component Catalina:type=DataSource,path=/MyApp,host=localhost,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/postgres"
```

Tomcat does start nonetheless, but my database code won't work, because my InitialContext.lookup ends up with nothing.

The postgres driver "postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar" is copied into the following folders:

I:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\common\lib

I:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\MyApp\WEB-INF\lib

Here is my MyApp/META-INF/context.xml:

```
<Context path="/MyApp" docBase="MyApp" crossContext="true" reloadable="true" debug="1">
    <Resource name="jdbc/postgres" 
        auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            username="postgres" 
            password="xxx" 
            driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
            url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/MyDatabase"
            maxWait="1000"
            maxActive="20" 
            maxIdle="10">
    </Resource>
</Context>
```

Here is an excerpt from my MyApp/WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<web-app>
…
<resource-ref>
    <description>
        Postgres resource reference to a factory
    </description>
    <res-ref-name>
        jdbc/postgres
    </res-ref-name>
    <res-type>
        javax.sql.DataSource
    </res-type>
    <res-auth>
        Container
    </res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

My project is deployed as a WAR by Eclipse and Tomcat explodes the WAR at startup as a folder. Now the strange thing: If I doesn't start Tomcat by hand, but by Eclipse, everything works!!! Tomcat doesn't come up with the error message above.
I have discovered Eclipse uses its own server.xml, context.xml etc. when it starts Tomcat itself, but even after comparing those files with Tomcat's regular config files the only difference I have spotted so far is the following additional line in Eclipse's server.xml before the closing "host" tag:

```
<Context docBase="MyApp" path="/MyApp" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:MyApp"/>
```

But even when I copy this line into Tomcat's own server.xml (without the "source"-attribute), it doesn't work without Eclipse. So Eclipse must do something "extra" which makes finding the DataSource possible, while the "normal" Tomcat configuration fails. Since I have to deploy the WAR on a different server (without Eclipse) I need help to make this run without Eclipse. I think my code is ok, since it works fine with Eclipse's Tomcat, but my configuration of Tomcat 5.5 must be faulty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending some more hours on the problem I have found a way to avoid Tomcat's error message. It seems my Eclipse configuration was faulty, because it was configured to add some of Tomcat's own jars into the folder "I:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\MyApp\WEB-INF\lib". After I changed Eclipse's setting to not include them but to use those libraries as **referenced** ones, they weren't included in the WAR file anymore and Tomcat started without error. To be more precise, the following three jars being duplicated in the lib of my webapp had to be removed to avoid the message: "naming-factory.jar", "naming-factory-dbcp.jar" and "naming-resources.jar".

Interestingly, although Tomcat was starting fine now, the result remained the same: If started from within Eclipse, my webapp would succeed with the JNDI lookup for the datasource, but when I started Tomcat without using Eclipse, the webapp still would fail when trying to access the database with the error message below:

```
Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
```

It took me some more time to get this working, too. I had to give up on the preferred method of defining an app-specific datasource, but defined a global one instead. I still don't know WHY Tomcat refuses to understand my app-specific settings, but at least one can circumvent the problem. Following are the steps that solved all my problems and allowed me the JNDI lookup:

1. Modifying the server.xml file in %CATALINA_HOME%/conf/server.xml inside the tag "GlobalNamingResources": Here I added the complete "Resource" tag section that was already in my context.xml (see above).
2. Modifying the context.xml file in %CATALINA_HOME%/conf/context.xml inside the "Context" tag: Here I added the line: `<ResourceLink global="jdbc/postgres" name="jdbc/postgres" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>`

I left the webapp-specific web.xml and context.xml unchanged (as seen above). Everything is working now. I post the solution to my problem I found myself in the hope others with a similar problem may benefit.

Comment: Just one additional note: The "cannot create JDBC driver" error does not happen with Tomcat 7. Today I put the same WAR file that let Tomcat 5.5. produce this error on a Tomcat 7 installation. With Tomcat 7 my workaround of defining a global resource is not necessary - it seems just Tomcat 5.5 had problems with the way I defined the app-specific datasource.

Comment: In your `MyApp/META-INF/context.xml`, the `Context` element should not have `path` or`docBase` set, since they are inferred when they defined at web application level. refer to [Context at Tomcat 5.5](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html)